# Issue when performing a segue on a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, cell

I'm currently learning Swift and trying to perform a segue when the user taps on one of the tableview cells that the app presents. At the moment, whenever the user performs this action, the next view controller is loaded successfully, but it seems that, for some reason, I cannot access any of its UI elements, as each time that I try to do it, I end up getting this error:

***fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***

The error points to the line in which I try to modify the text of one of the labels that are displayed on the next view controller

This is the **didSelectRowAt** function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: self)
}
```

and this is the **prepareForSegue** function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue1" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! UserViewController
        let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedRow) as! CustomCell

        destinationVC.usernameLabel.text = selectedCell.userName.text //this is where the error is pointing to
        destinationVC.bioLabel.text = selectedCell.bio.text
        destinationVC.userImage.image = selectedCell.photo.image

    }
}
```

I have no idea about what is causing this problem. My goal is to pass the data from the tapped cell to the next view controller, but this obviously is preventing me from doing so. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Mike. Are you using static or dynamic `UITableView` cells?

Comment: I'm using dynamic cells.

Comment: @Mike Vaugh, use `destinationVC.usernameLabel.text = selectedCell.userName.text  ?? " "`

Comment: @aircraft Tried it. Same error.

Comment: @Mike Vaugh, have you log the `selectedRow`? if it is `nil`? if you use deselected

Comment: the selectedrow is not nil, according to the log.

Comment: Mike, please check my answer. I believe I've arrived at a solution if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** I assumed that `userName` and `bio` were both `UITextField`s

Why don't you try something like this?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue1" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! UserViewController
        // Use of optional binding to make sure an indexPath exists
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)) as! CustomCell
            // Notice how we are not directly updating the label as before.
            destination.usernameText = cell.userName?.text
            destination.bioText = cell.bio?.text
        }
    }

}
```

**Now in `UserViewController`:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bioLabel: UILabel!
// What we will be passing the text to instead.
var usernameText: String?
var bioText: String?
```

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // update the labels with the text from the proper cell.
    usernameLabel?.text = usernameText
    bioLabel?.text = bioText
}
```

You can just do the same for your image, just different types. This has to do with the outlets not being allocated when used in `prepare(for segue:)`.

Comment: Mate, you fixed it! It's working beautifully now. Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer shortly.

Comment: Fantastic! Best of luck with your development. @MikeVaugh

Answer (score 0):

i had great issue with the prepare for segue method when trying the same thing with a UICollectionView.  The 2 are very similar so you should be able to change collectionview to tableview easily.

this is what i did... using variable selectedPack

in the view controller you want to segue to you need to set the variable

```
// passed packName from PackViewController
var selectedPack: String!
```

then in the viewcontroller you are selecting the cell

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // handle the segue to JourneyViewController with variable "selectedPack"
        // not sure why you need to set the storyboard but it works
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        //create instance of the viewcontroller
    let transportJourneyViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "JourneyViewController") as! JourneyViewController
        //value to pass - has been defined in journey
        transportJourneyViewController.selectedPack = INSERT_YOUR_VALUE_TO_PASS
        //present the vc
    self.present(transportJourneyViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

}
```

JourneyViewController is the storyboardID and ClassName of the viewcontroller you want to go to.set in the interface builder.

You'll also need to have the tableviewdatasource and tableviewdelegate defined at the top level of your view controllers and in the storyboard itself.

```
class JourneyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
```

Comment: I'm primarily looking to fix the issue with the tableview, specifically. However, using the UICollectionView sounds interesting indeed. I'll try it if I'm not able to do it with a tableview. Thanks!

Comment: just change "func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView" to "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView"  should work

Comment: and obviously the delegates will have to be changed from "UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate" to "UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate"